# using NSD to send and receive data

Tags: android, networking

I want to to share information between multiple android devices running the same app under the same network.

I have used *Network Service Discovery(NSD)* framework and devices detect each other.

How can I then share data between them?

Answer (score 0):

The protocol used by the NSD APIs allow you to exchange host addresses and port numbers. That means you can open a server socket on one device, advertise that as a service, and then connect to that port from the other machine.

As far as I can see, there's no higher level API provided in Android. Most of the existing APIs seem to be geared towards Cloud data exchange, not local data exchange.